# Java app loads JNI differently when started via Ant

Tags: java, macos, ant, java-native-interface, rxtx

I'm using RXTX in my Java application which includes a JNI library. I placed the .jni file in `/Libray/Java/Extensions`. When I start my application manually via the usual `java -jar /path/to/app.jar` everything works fine. However when I try to start it via Netbeans or Ant it fails with

> ```
>  [java] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Library/Java/Extensions/librxtxSerial.jnilib:  no suitable image found.  Did find:  /Library/Java/Extensions/librxtxSerial.jnilib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
>  [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Library/Java/Extensions/librxtxSerial.jnilib:  no suitable image found.  Did find:  /Library/Java/Extensions/librxtxSerial.jnilib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
>  [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>  [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1823)
>  [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
>  [java]     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
>  [java]     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
>  [java]     at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
> ```

Analogue behaviour when I move the .jni somewhere else and point the JVM to it using `-Djava.library.path`. It works manually but fails with Ant.

I'm using Java 1.6 64Bit, Ant 1.7.1, RXTX 2.1-7r2 (stable) running Mac OS X 10.6.4

Answer (score 0):

Does your ant java task have `<jvmarg value="-Djava.library.path=location-of-your-native-library"/>` set?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried that line in my build.xml. That is what I meant to describe as anologue behavior. It fails with the same error I posted.